# Use CMD commands in C# For showing Tasklist

Tags: c#, command-line, cmd

I need to find the PID number for a process using C# and tasklist in the CMD.

the PID number needs to be put into a textbox in a c# form.

The code for finding the pid number in Command prompt is this.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2"  %a in ('  Tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /nh') do @echo %b
```

But I don´t know how to integrate CMD commands into C# winform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing in .NET by using `Process.GetProcessesByName` and then outputting the process `Id`:

```
foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Id);
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use the cmd window and capture the output, you can create a process that will run `cmd.exe` and pass it the command line you want to execute (add a `/C` at the beginning, which tells `cmd.exe` to close the cmd window after running). You also want to `RedirectStandardOutput`, which allows you to capture the output of the command that was run. Then you can use `proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` to get each line that was returned:

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/C for /f \"tokens=1,2\" %a in " + 
            "('Tasklist /fi \"imagename eq notepad.exe\" /nh') do @echo %b",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
    }
};

proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();

while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly initiate a command prompt window ( Console ) and capture its stdout and stderr streams to grab the data and then parse it and show it in a windows forms control,

at the same time, usually in a case like this the `Process` class part of standard .NET Framework is used to retrieve any information of a running process on thw Windows machine,

have a look at this methos in MSDN for example: `Process.GetProcessesByName` or any other method of the `Process` class, that way you can do it without running any command in any console window.